# apt-get install new packeges, avoid others

Tags: debian, curl, apt-get

Look at this entry:

```
root@vivid-75:~# apt-get --no-install-recommends install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libacl1 libattr1 libc-bin libc6 libc6-i686 libcurl3 libgnutls26 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libp11-kit0 librtmp0 libsmbclient libssl1.0.0
  libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtinfo5 libwbclient0 locales multiarch-support openssh-client openssh-server samba samba-common smbclient winbind
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc krb5-doc krb5-user ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere rssh molly-guard ufw openbsd-inetd inet-superserver smbldap-tools ldb-tools ctdb
Recommended packages:
  krb5-locales tdb-tools libpam-winbind libnss-winbind
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libkrb53
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libp11-kit0 librtmp0 libssl1.0.0 libtinfo5 multiarch-support
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libacl1 libattr1 libc-bin libc6 libc6-i686 libcurl3 libgnutls26 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libsmbclient libtalloc2 libtdb1 libwbclient0 locales
  openssh-client openssh-server samba samba-common smbclient winbind
22 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1142 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.9 MB/49.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

I just want to install the **NEW** packages, not the **EXTRA**, **SUGGESTED** or **RECOMMENDED**:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libp11-kit0 librtmp0 libssl1.0.0 libtinfo5 multiarch-support
```

No lucky reading man page for apt-get.

It's possible to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `curl libp11-kit0 librtmp0 libssl1.0.0 libtinfo5 multiarch-support` are **required dependencies**. They must be installed in order for the package you want to work properly.

Since the list

```
  libacl1 libattr1 libc-bin libc6 libc6-i686 libcurl3 libgnutls26 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libsmbclient libtalloc2 libtdb1 libwbclient0 locales
  openssh-client openssh-server samba samba-common smbclient winbind
```

looks like an upgrade list, they may have been queued for an upgrade because of some other package or packages.

You can always remove the "extra" packages later.

Comment: I don't want to update i.e: `samba` cause it's running ok. That's the problem.

Comment: I've never had a package update break anything. It is important to keep a regularly updated system. After a quick glance at the Samba changelog, I think that there could be a security update for it. Also, if you're running a server and are afraid of downtime due to an update, don't worry about it; an update to any of those in the list will not require a restart to your system.

Comment: I forgot to mention on the question that these packages are from Wheeze repo that is a testing (unstable) repository, not the Squeeze. Anyway, I updated those packages, let's see and pray. Thank you anyway.